# Rewrite Multiple Parameter URL htaccess and PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have tried severally for couple of hours but not  getting it right. I am new to htaccess and all i'm googling seem not to help. How do I rewrite this url

`http://localhost/appgat/profile/?service-provider=Tech&job=29`

to something like this

`http://localhost/appgat/service-provider/tech/29`

I have tried several tricks that I don't even understand their meaning including this last one
`RewriteRule ^service-provider/([0-9a-z]+) profile/service-provider=$1&job=$2 [NC,L]`

Comment: Why don't you use a micro framework like [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/)?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @DanielO. But that isn't going to solve my instant problem now. I will read more about SlimPHP later. Thanks

Comment: Ok then maybe read my article about this topic. I hope it will help you. https://gist.github.com/odan/e791bb29e2a1eab4ac6f2be4bbf86e12

Comment: First of all, are you doing it the right way around? You don't rewrite the first to the second, it's the other way around. Read the duplicate and update your question with a lot more detail if you still need help.